# Conditional WCF DataContract Serialization

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, datacontract

While working with the WCF I was facing a strange issue.

Lets say,

I have a Student Class

```
public class Student
{
     [DataMember]
     public int32  ID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public DateTime? CreatedDate  { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public Gender Gender { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get; set; }
}


[OperationContract]
Student GetStudentDetail  (StudentRequest request);

[OperationContract]
Student GetStudent  (StudentDetailRequest request);
```

and I´m returning a response as a `Student` complex type from `wcf` with a method name `GetStudent()` which works fine. but in another scenerio I have one more web method called `GetStudentDetail()` in which i want to return more datamembers from Student class like:

```
[DataMember]
public int32 Age{ get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string Location { get; set; }
```

If I add new `Datamember` in class `Student` it automatically showing in response of schema for `GetStudent()` method which I don't want .. actually I don't want to return new fields in schema to `GetStudent()` method. So the problem is here: I want to expose new datamembers of `Student` class only for `GetStudentDetail()` method .

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about introducing DetailedStudent class and inherite it from Student?

Comment: No I dont want to make DetailedStudent class; just looking to return only student class for both web methods with differeent datamembers. any logic?

Comment: And how this should be represented on client side? As two different classes?

Comment: its not automatically showing. Both of your methods are returning the same `student` type. you are asking something impossible unless you want to create two different types.

Comment: Hey Guys, Dont say its  not possible , at least in IT :) ..they are ways ..I´m trying out.. Hope if you understand the question can  help.

Comment: Regarding : And how this should be represented on client side? As two different classes?  -- actually this is requirement and we need to just create schema as it is .. if it is GetStudent() method then 4 fields should come blah blah.. if it is GetStudentDetail() then 6-7 fields should come.. but response type should be same always.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of achieving what you want to do. As other commentators have said the type you are returning is the **same from both service operations**.

The only thing you could do is serialize your Student type and embed it as a raw [WCF Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type, and expose this as the return type in your service operations.

Then you can handle manually the deserialization **to the client side type of your choice** depending on which service operation was called.

This, however, would be a ridiculous use-case, when you could, as has been already suggested, simply create another service type and expose it over the other operation.